# Facing an issue for fetching and saving value from datagridview to variable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am not getting value from datagrid to a variable.
I tried following code. I'm not getting any syntax or compilation error. But still code is not working.

```
public void get_bnamegv1()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
     {
         string textname = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
         temp_count.Text = textname;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Try eliminating ConvertToString() method.   Results are probably already a string and using ConvertToString() is probable returning the type System.String.

Comment: thanks for quick replay jdweng. But i am facing an error if i remove ConvertToString().

Comment: are sure that Cell[1] is having values. please check if Cell[1] has values. 
  
OR  

You can try  
string textname = (string)datagridview2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;

Comment: Ajit Medhekar, thanks for your response. Even though grid has a value it is returning null for the label...

Comment: my issue is, form contains 3 datagrid in different tabs, but fetching value from grid 1 is working fine with same code but fetching value from grid2 and grid3 is not happening with same piece of code...

Comment: Try this :                string textname = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1] == null ? "" : dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for getting an empty string is the value from data grid view column is null, which after converting to string becomes empty string.
Can you try

```
dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()
```

in place of

```
Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
```

If you get a System.NullReferenceException then you are getting null value from grid's cell.

Comment: Thank you Ankit Bharadwaj for your response. But this what error i get if change code as your suggestion. (Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: when i check by adding breakpoint during runtime, the fetched values will be displayed in pop-up tip, but its not saving to variable or any other objects like textbox or label.

Comment: That's what I told you that if you get this exception, there is something wrong with the data on your grid and not the way you are retrieving data. So you are investigating at the wrong place for your problem. You should be looking into the code which is adding data to the grid.
If in case you want to ignore the null values, you can use this:
dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value?.ToString()